# I'm having unacceptable Keyboard and mouse delay while using Linux Mint 18.3 64 bit with the Xfce user interface

Tags: linux-mint

Keyboard and mouse delay while using  Linux Mint 18.3 64 bit with the Xfce user interface.

I apologize if this issue has been addressed or a very similar issue has been addressed, a search did not turn anything up, but that may be because I didn’t use a good search term.

This in a new machine that I assembled from parts, I installed Windows 10 and then Linux Mint 18.3 as a dual boot.

The Windows 10 partition does not have a discernible amount of mouse and keyboard lag.

In Linux Mint 18.3, the mouse and keyboard have an unacceptable amount of lag. It doesn’t make any difference if I use wired or wireless keyboards and mice. I have installed Solaar and it’s information window shows that Solaar recognizes both of the Logitech receivers I’m using.

It’s also note worthy that the wireless mouse and keyboard work without noticeable lag on my older HP small form factor 32 bit machine, running Linux Mint 18.1 with the MATE user interface.

Results of running the inxi -Fxz command on the 64 bit machine: (Linux Mint 18.3, Xfce.)

```
<username>@<username>-Z370XP-SLI ~ $ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: <username>-Z370XP-SLI Kernel: 4.10.0-38-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 (Gtk 2.24.28) Distro: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Machine:   System: Gigabyte product: Z370XP SLI v: Default string
           Mobo: Gigabyte model: Z370XP SLI-CF v: x.x
           Bios: American Megatrends v: F3 date: 09/06/2017
CPU:       Hexa core Intel Core i5-8600K (-MCP-) cache: 9216 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 43200
           clock speeds: max: 4300 MHz 1: 3971 MHz 2: 4125 MHz 3: 4124 MHz
           4: 4197 MHz 5: 4299 MHz 6: 4198 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 3e92 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: fbdev,intel (unloaded: vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 256 bits)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Device a2f0 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-38-generic
Network:   Card: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
           driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k bus-ID: 00:1f.6
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 507.9GB (3.0% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: HFS500G32TND size: 500.1GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: USB_DISK_2.0 size: 7.7GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 212G used: 6.6G (4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.46GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-0
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 27.8C mobo: 16.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 213 Uptime: 26 min Memory: 1157.6/7855.8MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Results of running the inxi -Fxz command on the 32 bit machine: (Linux Mint 18.1, MATE.)
[While wireless keyboard and mouse in use.]

```
<username>@HPDesktop ~ $ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: HPDesktop Kernel: 4.4.0-75-generic i686 (32 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: MATE 1.16.2 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3)
           Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Machine:   System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP Compaq dc7900 Small Form Factor
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 3031h
           Bios: Hewlett-Packard v: 786G1 v01.16 date: 03/05/2009
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core2 Duo E8400 (-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 11969
           clock speeds: max: 3000 MHz 1: 1998 MHz 2: 1998 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel 4 Series Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1280x1024@60.02hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Q45/Q43 x86/MMX/SSE2
           GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 11.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-75-generic
Network:   Card: Intel 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
           driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: 1100 bus-ID: 00:19.0
           IF: enp0s25 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 192.1GB (13.7% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SAMSUNG_HD161GJ size: 160.0GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdc model: STORE_N_GO size: 32.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 145G used: 21G (15%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 2.07GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 42.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 186 Uptime: 11 min Memory: 840.5/1943.5MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

I have adjusted the mouse acceleration to zero and the sensitivity to 1Px, the result is a somewhat slowed down pointer / cursor, but still difficult to use. The key repeat delay and, repeat speed are very close to the values recommended by Xfce, blinking is off. There is still a very noticeable delay between pressing a key and the character appearing on the screen / desktop.

---

Some additional information:

Linux Mint 18.1 64 bit with the xfce user interface;

Results of running the ps aux command:

```
<username>  4216  0.0  0.8 1606040 68888 ?       Sl   10:04   0:00 /usr/lib/chromi
<username>  4225  0.0  0.8 1604424 65064 ?       Sl   10:04   0:00 /usr/lib/chromi
<username>  4237  0.0  0.1 475564 13108 ?        S    10:04   0:00 /usr/lib/chromi
<username>  4251  0.0  0.8 1616308 70144 ?       Sl   10:04   0:00 /usr/lib/chromi
<username>  4255  0.0  0.8 1607528 66948 ?       Sl   10:04   0:00 /usr/lib/chromi
<username>  4346  0.2  1.3 1677152 110828 ?      Sl   10:05   0:03 /usr/lib/chromi
root      4375  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:05   0:00 [kworker/2:0]
root      4390  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:06   0:00 [kworker/u12:1]
root      4569  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:12   0:00 [kworker/3:1]
root      4624  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:13   0:00 [kworker/2:2]
root      4698  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:17   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
root      4742  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:17   0:00 [kworker/0:1]
<username>  4777 19.1  4.7 2055840 386104 ?      Sl   10:18   1:20 /usr/lib/chromi
root      4934  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:23   0:00 [kworker/1:1]
root      4960  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:23   0:00 [kworker/2:1]
nobody    5006  0.0  0.0  52860   396 ?        S    10:24   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsma
nobody    5007  0.0  0.0  52860   396 ?        S    10:24   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsma
root      5011  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:24   0:00 [kworker/5:1]
nobody    5012  0.0  0.0  52860   396 ?        S    10:24   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsma
nobody    5015  0.0  0.0  52860   396 ?        S    10:25   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsma
<username>  5040  1.3  0.4 506428 35924 ?        Sl   10:25   0:00 xfce4-terminal
<username>  5044  0.0  0.0  22376  4884 pts/2    Ss   10:25   0:00 bash
<username>  5061  0.0  0.0  37360  3276 pts/2    R+   10:25   0:00 ps aux
```

Results of running the lsmod command 3-Mar-18

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
binfmt_misc            20480  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
dm_crypt               28672  1
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             200704  0
i915                 1449984  0
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
drm_kms_helper        151552  1 i915
drm                   352256  2 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         126976  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
aesni_intel           167936  4455
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  2230 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    77824  16 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
hci_uart               98304  0
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                16384  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             557056  11 hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm
intel_lpss_acpi        16384  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_acpi
acpi_pad              180224  0
mac_hid                16384  0
acpi_als               16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
industrialio           69632  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
parport_pc             32768  1
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
autofs4                40960  2
btrfs                1089536  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  1 btrfs
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         20480  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  2 uas
hid_logitech_hidpp     28672  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
usbhid                 53248  0
mxm_wmi                16384  0
e1000e                249856  0
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               16384  1 ptp
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    16384  1 mxm_wmi
video                  40960  1 i915
i2c_hid                20480  0
hid                   118784  9 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
fjes                   77824  0
```

From the Linux Mint forums at Linux Mint’s official site:

> Try the latest kernel of the 4.13 series*. After installing it, reboot.
>   Update Manager - panel: View - Linux kernels.

My reply after updating the kernel:

> ...updating the kernel helped and now the system is more nearly useful, that's right, still some response delay. The keyboard still has a considerable delay. The mouse has less delay then previously, still over shoots and is hard to center over smaller action buttons. Again, overall an improvement in responsiveness, regrettably, not yet at the point where the response time is equal to other machines I have.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start would be to figure out why the machine running Linux Mint 18.3 is using software rendering. Your `inxi` output for the machine with the performance issues says `GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe` as opposed to `GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Q45/Q43 x86/MMX/SSE2` for the computer that works fine.

Comment: dsstorefile, What, discouraged from thanking people, how strange. So, although I have been running a Linux rig for a long time, I'm not that proficient with terminal commands. I will need to look up GLX renderer and find out what that means. FWIW; I learned about the inxi -Fxz command over at Linux Mint's site, it's suggested there that including the output from that command is very helpful. I only included the inxi -Fxz output from my other machine on a whim, that may have proved more helpful than I thought. tks Nilo

Answer (score 2):

Linux Mint 19 supports my processor, so upgrading solved the issue.